# View with dropdown filter criteria for all nodes

Tags: views

I want to make a view of a Content Type with exposed filters as the attached image shows. First criteria filter would be the book type that is a field of the Content Type BOOK. Second filter criteria would be all the nodes of the Content Type BOOK. Is it possible?

[image: example]

Comment: If the first one selects the content type....the other content types will also be listed.

Comment: sure in general a filter form is a drupal form supporting the Form API. a subset of this API is `#ajax` calls. Drupal also ships with `jQuery` bundled. You can make this work with some custom code and javascript.

Comment: @2pha BOOK TYPE is not different CT is just a field of the BOOK CT like a category. So, tenken, Form API could help me on this? You propose custom coding?

Comment: I am unsure of the structure you have and what you actually want to achieve. Do you want the second dropdown to be dependent on the first?

Comment: yep, that's right, I do

Comment: If a Book Type is selected I would like the Book dropdown list to be shorten. Now, if a Book is selected I would like the result on search to be this specific book node. And if just the Book Type is selected (not a specific Book) I would like the search result to be all the books(nodes) of this type (which would be just a CT field to categorize the books). And as far as I can see, @2pha, I should do some custom coding, a custom module or smth?